# Recursive Definition for Logarithm

Tags: recurrence-relations, logarithms

Is it possible to express $\log(n)$ in terms of itself, using only elementary functions, e.g., similar to (the incorrect made-up equation):
\begin{equation*}
\log(n) = e^n * \log(n - 1) + \sin(n) * \log(n - 2)
\end{equation*}
I know this can be done for e.g. $\sin$ and $\cos$, since
\begin{equation*}
\sin(n) = \sin(n - 1) * \cos(1) + \cos(n - 1) * \sin(1)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\cos(n) = \cos(n - 1) * \cos(1) - \sin(n - 1) * \sin(1)
\end{equation*}
This question is more of theoretical interest to me.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log ab = \log a + \log b$$

Before the advent of digital computers, that was the formula used to build up log tables very rapidly.